# Can I use Go lang for automation test instead of robot framework test?

Tags: api, selenium, go, robotframework

I want to test API, the program was developed by Golang.
If I want to create the automation test, Should I use Go for API test or use go selenium for API testing? Who have any ideas?

Comment: What kind of API is it? And if it's an API, not html UI, what does selenium has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is REST APIs then, [rest-assured](http://rest-assured.io/), will be the good option to automate.